# How to ask the expression 'And?'?

Tags: conjonctions, interjections, coordination

How do you say the expression "and?" ? For example, if my friend has to say something to me but does not want to, and I ask "and?" after each word he says slowly, do I just say « et ?????? ­­» ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Et alors ?*** is commonly used in that case.

Beware that **it must be asked an interrogative/ascending way** like in the Henri Salvador song "Zorro est arrivé" (thanks to 変幻出没 for his comment) otherwise it means "**So what?**".

Alternatively, you might also use ***Et puis ?*** or ***Mais encore ?*** as Graffito suggested.

Comment: "Et alors?" is a question for "what happens then?". If you mean "What else", you may say "**Mais encore**".

Comment: @Graffito "Et alors ?" has a broader spectrum of meanings.

Comment: Practical use of "et alors ?" [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDTIjOWKG-4)

Comment: "Et donc" is also appropriate in this frame. "Et alors" can carry kind of a negative meaning such as "I don't care", so be careful with the way you say it.

Comment: @Puzzled "Et donc" can be negative too depending on how the sentence is pronounced. In any case, I already warned about the tone issue in the second line of my answer which looks to have been missed by several readers for some reason. Editing it now to make it clearer.

Comment: @jiliagre Wow, I had completely missed that, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really agree with [jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/1109/jlliagre)'s answer. In my opinion, "Et alors ?" often means "What you just said is useless".
I agree "Et alors ?" can be used in a positive way, but my point is that it may be confusing.

I would use one of those instead :

> Oui... ?
>   Ensuite ?
>   Et puis ?
>   Et... ?
>   Allez, accouche ! (slang, saying you can't wait anymore !)
>   Vas-y, accouche ! (slang, saying you can't wait anymore !)

Comment: Quand "est alors" est utilisé dans le sens de "on s'en fou", "ça n'a rien à voir avec le sujet", généralement "et alors" n'est pas utilisé seul. On a plutôt "et alors, qu'est-ce que cela apporte ?", "et alors, quel est le rapport", etc. Alors que quand on dit "et alors ?" avec une intention montante on attend clairement la suite. L'intonation ne laisse aucun doute sur quel "et alors" est utilisé de façon générale.

Comment: @random, I already mentioned the required tone to avoid a confusion with "So what?".

Comment: @変幻出没 "Et alors ?" peut aussi s'utiliser seul pour dire "on s'en fou". Seule l'intonation permet de différencier les 2 sens opposés. En imaginant les 2 intonation, elles me paraissent tout de même assez proches, surtout sur une si courte phrase, ce qui peut amener à mon avis à une confusion.

Comment: @jlliagre As I said to 変幻出没, on such a short sentence, it may be hard to distinguish the tone, since I believe the positive and negative tones are quite similar here, which may be confusing in my opinion. Personnaly, I wouldn't use "Et alors ?" in a positive way, that is the reason I suggest something else.

Comment: @Random À la rigueur pour une oreille non entraînée la distinction peut être un peu dure; cependant en plus de l'intonation montante, "et alors ?" dans le sens, "quelle est la suite ?" la phrase est souvent allongée et traînante (intriguée) contrairement à rapide et sèche dans le cas inverse. Cependant, dans les deux cas, "et alors ?" demande clairement la suite. Par exemple. B (ne voit pas le rapport): "(Ouais,) et alors ?" A: " 'et alors' attends une seconde que je t'explique et tu vas comprendre".